# Definition of "containment" in subsets.

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I am having a hard time understanding the definition of "containment." I'm following Munkres' book on Topology, 2000.

> $d$ is a metric, let $y \in B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$. Then I can find
>   $\delta >0$ such that $y\in B_d(y,\delta) \subset B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$

He proves this result, which I have no problem with. But then, in his book the notation $\subset$ does not necessarily mean that if $A \subset B$ that $A$ is a proper subset. In this result he has derived he keeps using the word "containment". does he mean here that $B_d(y, \delta)$ should be a proper subset of $B_d(x, \epsilon)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that  $y $ might equal  $x $ and  $\delta  $ might be  $\epsilon  $, for instance,  so the "containment" needn't be proper...  but if $\delta \lt \epsilon  $, in $\mathbb R ^n $, say, with the usual metric , it is of course proper...

Answer (score 1):

In general, "$A$ is contained in $B$" is just another way of saying "$A$ is a subset of $B$".  It doesn't have to be a proper subset.